# How to scale and center text vertically in a fluid layout? (using CSS)

Tags: css, fonts, scale, vertical-alignment, fluid-layout

I have a fluid layout consisting of a header and a content area. The header is meant to occupy 10% of the window's height and the content area is expected to occupy the remaining 90%. Text in the entire screen should scale proportionally to the window's height. Also text in the header should be centered vertically. I am able to meet all these requirements except the last one. Anyone know how to do this?

Here's what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/nareshbhatia/h2s4h/

I am using Em units to do relative sizing of the text. I use JavaScript to change the font-size of the `body` element whenever the window is resized. This approach scales the fonts beautifully for the entire window. Finally, I tried to center the header text vertically by setting the line-height of the header to be the same as its height (i.e. 10%). This usually centers the text vertically (when the height is defined in pixels), but in this case the text does not center vertically. Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Edit** The jsFiddle is updated to show the suggested answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line-height approach centers the text when you only have one line. You are using percentages, so I think [this question might help in that respect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071987/line-height-as-a-percentage-not-working).

What you could do instead is use some more jQuery or JS to, on load:

- Measure the outer height of the paragraph (or whatever element you are using) in the `.content`
- Calculate the bottom `offset` of this paragraph in relation with the `.content` (how much space you have remaining from the bottom border of the paragraph to the bottom border of the .content div)
- Divide the remainder in two, and add that number as a top `margin` or top `position` for the paragraph.

This will let you have longer text without messing with the line-height.

If you want a pure css solution, check these [alternative ways of centering vertically](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/).

Comment: I am only interested in centering the one line in the header. So your links were very helpful. I used the `display: table-cell` method. The jsFiddle is updated to show the solution.