# Issue with line-height within a paragraph

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using WordPress and applying a class to a section of post text.

Here is my post text

```
<p>
    <span class="disclaimer">A really long line of text that covers more than one line.</span>
</p>
```

Here is my CSS

```
p > .disclaimer {
    font-size: 50%;
    line-height: 50%;
}
```

Here is my issue:
 
The font becomes 50% smaller but the line-height does not. No matter what value I input for line-height it will not size properly. The text shows huge spacing when the line wraps around.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071987/line-height-as-a-percentage-not-working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the `line-height` on the `p` rather than the `span`:

```css
p {
  line-height: 50%;
  width:100px; /* for example only*/
}
.disclaimer {
  font-size: 50%;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="disclaimer">A really long line of text that covers more than one line.</span></p>
```

Comment: You beat me too :) But only for note: It's a good practice to use `Unitless Line Heights` [css-triks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-height/) , [another link](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2006/02/08/unitless-line-heights/). So you can try `line-height: 0.5` instead `line-height: 50%;`

Comment: @pgk, I would have used 0.5 too but as 50% was in the original question, I didn't want to change too much

Comment: @Pete - Of course I mentioned this ony to the future readers :).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
p > .disclaimer {
font-size: 50%;
line-height: 50%;
display:block;}
```

Comment: While this can answer the question, it's better to provide some explanations about how this code help.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

`line-height` works differently for **inline** elements than it does for **block** elements.

Try `display: block;` in your span's css, or if you need to use the span as inlined element you can reference [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28370374/5594521)

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the quick response.