# line-height in % is relative is relative to the viewport or font?

Tags: css

I'm testing line-height property. Line-height in % is relative to what?

line-height: normal;
line-height: 1.6;
line-height: 80%; % is it relative to what?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [line-height as a percentage not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071987/line-height-as-a-percentage-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

A `line-height` specified as a percentage `%` will be relative to the calculated font size of the element.

This is answered pretty well (with examples) in the [MDN `line-height` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height):

> **`normal`**
>
> Depends on the user agent. Desktop browsers (including Firefox) use a default value of roughly **1.2**, depending on the element's `font-family`.
>
> **`<number>` (unitless)**
>
> The used value is this unitless `<number>` multiplied by the element's own font size. The computed value is the same as the specified `<number>`. In most cases, **this is the preferred way** to set `line-height` and avoid unexpected results due to inheritance.
>
> **`<length>`**
>
> The specified `<length>` is used in the calculation of the line box height. Values given in `em` units may produce unexpected results.
>
> **`<percentage>`**
>   Relative to the font size of the element itself. The computed value is this `<percentage>` multiplied by the element's computed font size. **Percentage** values may produce unexpected results (see the second example below).

The same is said in the specification for [CSS Level 2 (Revision 1): `line-height`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height).

Comment: Thanks my friend.